# Why is it printing all three printing statements?

Tags: perl

```
my %hash = ( 0=> , 1=>"Man");
my $key=0;
print "Exists\n"    if exists $hash{$key};
print "Defined\n"   if defined $hash{$key};
print "True\n"      if $hash{$key};
```

Why is the above Perl code printing all three print statements?

It should print only Exists, shouldn't it?

Comment: Did you try `print "$hash{$key}\n";` ? Might possibly help out.

Comment: @Chris: nice way to give him a fishing rod instead of the fish :-)

Comment: Try `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%hash;`  This will help, too.

Answer (score 22):

**`use strict; use warnings;`**. Always.

Your hash declaration is not doing what you think it's doing, it has an odd number of elements.

Try this:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my %hash = ( 0=> , 1=>"Man");
print Dumper(%hash);
```

You'll see that `$hash{0}` is set to 1, `$hash{"Man"}` exists but is `undef`, and `$hash{1}` does not exist at all. i.e. your hash declaration is equivalent to:

```
my %hash = (0 => 1, "Man" => undef);
```

**Why** is this happening? It's because:

`=>` is essentially an equivalent of `,`

[List value constructors](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors) work that way, e.g. `($a,,$b)` is equivalent to `($a,$b)`

Relevant quotes from that document:

> The **`=>`** operator is mostly just a more visually distinctive synonym for a comma, but it also arranges for its left-hand operand to be interpreted as a string if it's a bareword that would be a legal simple identifier.

And:

> The null list is represented by **`()`**. Interpolating it in a list has no effect. Thus **`((),(),())`** is equivalent to **`()`**. Similarly, interpolating an array with no elements is the same as if no array had been interpolated at that point.
>
> (...)
>
> The list **`1,,3`** is a concatenation of two lists, **`1,`** and **`3`**, the first of which ends with that optional comma. **`1,,3`** is **`(1,),(3)`** is **`1,3`** (And similarly for **`1,,,3`** is **`(1,),(,),3`** is **`1,3`** and so on.) Not that we'd advise you to use this obfuscation.

Apply this to your code:

```
   (0 => , 1 => "Man");
is (0 , , 1 , "Man");
is (0 , 1 , "Man");
```

Comment: The main point is that `=>` is merely syntactic sugar for `,`, which is why `0` gets mapped to `1` instead of to `undef`

Comment: I didn't even know one cat write horrible things like `(1,,,,,,,2)` in `perl` prior to this post.

Comment: Or even "horribler" `(1=>=>=>=>=>2)` - mix in comas if you feel adventurous :-)

Comment: Thanks Mat, I was not sure that '=>' is equivalent to ','(or ,1 would be 1 in this example). I was just trying to explain between defined and exists through this example and was scared to see the different outputs for  my %hash = ( 0=> , 1=>"Man") and my %hash = (1=>"Man", 0=>). After your explanation it is now very clear what exactly happens when we assign an array into a hash. Thanks again mate.

Answer (score 9):

Always, *always*, ***ALWAYS*** `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in your code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = ( 0=> , 1=>"Man");
my $key=0;
print "Exists\n"    if exists $hash{$key};
print "Defined\n"   if defined $hash{$key};
print "True\n"      if $hash{$key};
```

Output:

```
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at - line 3.
```

If you want an element to exist but not be defined, use `undef`:

```
my %hash = ( 0=> undef, 1=>"Man");
```

Answer (score 4):

`use warnings;` and you'll see `Odd number of elements in hash assignment`.

That's it! You've got (0=>1, "Man"=>undef).

Answer (score 4):

Try enabling warnings.  This line

```
my %hash = ( 0=> , 1=>"Man");
```

creates a hash ( 0 => '1', 'Man' => undef );